# Cakephp and CKeditor file manager

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor with Cakephp. All works fine but I'm having problems with file browser.

When I click on it, it doesn't give me file manager. Instead it comes up with something like

```
Index of /app/webroot/pdf
```

I've got below set up with config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/pdf/';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/pdf/';

};
```

There is webroot/pdf folder but it doesn't pick up...Is there a reason why it's doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point your vhost for this app to app/webroot not app/ or try an absolute path in the editor config.